# Error: Failed to write input into the OpenMAX buffer

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to encode uncompressed video in H.265; however, when I write the following pipeline I receive an error message that I cannot resolve. I am following the example code in Tegra X1 Multimedia User Guide, and I do not understand why the following pipeline does not work. I am a beginner in video compression so any help would be very useful. The code/error message:

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$ gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=small_mem_vid.mov ! 'video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, framerate=(fraction)30/1, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720' ! omxh265enc ! filesink location=new_encode.mov -e  

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ... 

Inside NvxLiteH264DecoderLowLatencyInitNvxLiteH264DecoderLowLatencyInit set DPB and MjstreamingInside         NvxLiteH265DecoderLowLatencyInitNvxLiteH265DecoderLowLatencyInit set DPB and MjstreamingPipeline is PREROLLING ...  
Framerate set to : 30 at NvxVideoEncoderSetParameterNvMMLiteOpen : Block : BlockType = 8  
===== MSENC =====  
NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 8 
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstOMXH265Enc-omxh265enc:omxh265enc-omxh265enc0: Could not write to resource.
```

Additional debug info:

```
/dvs/git/dirty/git-master_linux/external/gstreamer/gst-omx/omx/gstomxvideoenc.c(2139): gst_omx_video_enc_handle_frame ():   /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstOMXH265Enc-omxh265enc:omxh265enc-omxh265enc0:  
Failed to write input into the OpenMAX buffer  
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.  
Setting pipeline to NULL ...  
Freeing pipeline ...  
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: @chema989 it is mcve .. gst-launch pipe is minimal complete and indeed verifiable :) its the scripting language of gstreamer ..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the .mov file is really uncompressed video?  The .mov extension is commonly used for quicktime video.  You could use "mediainfo" in Linux to discover more details about the format of the file.  In that case I don't think you can go directly from filesrc to the encoder.  You probably need a qtdemux and a decoder, maybe avdec_h264 depending on what mediainfo shows.

You also might want to enable some more detailed debugging:
 export GST_DEBUG=*:4

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I do know for a fact that the .mov file is uncompressed video because when I look at the video Properties it says that it's codec is uncompressed packed YUV.  I think it may have something to do with trying to create an .mov file using filesink.  What is the most common video extension for H.265 video?

Comment: h.265 video could be contained in different media container formats, .mp4 is common.  HEVC is the fourcc value for h.265.  Did you try other encoders on your platform besides h.265?  Maybe the problem is specific to that encoder?